# 2008R2 RDS Redirect RDP Request

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, rds

I have a 2008 R2 with AD, DHCP, RDS - The server acts as a router for the internal network. I'm trying to connect through RDP from the internet to computers on the internal network through RDS. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

You best bet would be [Remote Desktop Gateway](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-is-a-Remote-Desktop-Gateway-server) (or Terminal Services Gateway).  This creates a gateway via port 443 to allow you to access Remote Desktop Servers (this includes Windows Professional/Ultimate edition workstations offering RD access) behind the gateway.  It also allows you to control who can get to where using [Authorization Policies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731435.aspx), which is much better than just opening up ports on your firewall.

Since it uses TLS, you would need a certificate your RD clients trust to avoid warnings on each connection setup.

Comment: thanks for the edits..  I need to work on being more complete when I answer questions on here.

Comment: Can you go a bit more indepth on actual configuration Mike? Or point me to somewhere that shows how to achieve this config

Comment: Remote Desktop Gateway is a Server Role under Remote Desktop Services in Windows Server 2008.  A Step by Step from Microsoft can be found here  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5177  Start there and let us know how far you get.

Answer (score 2):

RDP to the RDS server. RDP ("jump") from that one to the next

Comment: I doubt very much that the performance would be acceptable.

Comment: Depends on what you need RDP access for

Comment: This is what I'm doing right now but that's not really making use of RDS at all...

Comment: Usually with adequate bandwidth, jumping is workable.  Though don't expect to stream video on it.

Answer (score 2):

If there are only a few of them you could forward ports.  One excellent way to do this in linux is to use SSH to forward the port dynamically; I don't know if windows has any like facility.

You could also use internet-routeable ("real") IP addresses on your internal network and allow RDP through the firewall.